# A, An, The Are Prepositions?

Tags: grammar

Ignore the rest

Somebody Told me in a middle of a Grammar test that A, An, The Are Prepositions. Any Literate person can en-light me, I think I'm Lost in darkness somewhere.

Comment: I have never encountered any classification which calls those _prepositions_. They are traditionally **articles**, now considered a subset of **determiners**.

Answer (score 1):

"A", "an", and "the" are articles. You can read here about their function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar). They modify nouns directly. As parts of speech, they fall under the heading of adjectives.

Prepositions are another part of speech entirely. They include words like on, of, with, to, at, in, etc., and they generally combine a noun with other words in a way that conveys information about it. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preposition#examples